# two different edge color map on the same graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have done the following code to plot colors of nodes and edges color map from files :

```
## NODES COLORS##
Active={}
with open('NWWE/node'+str('{:03d}'.format(i))+'.txt', 'r') as f:
    for j in f: 
        a,b=j.split(',')
        Active[a]=b[0] 
for node in G.nodes():
        G.node[node]['category'] = Active[node]
color_map = {'0':'b', '1':'r'}

##EDGES COLOR MAP##
with open('NWWE/edges'+str('{:03d}'.format(i))+'.txt', 'r') as f:
    for k in f: 
        a,b,c=k.split(',')
        G[a][b]['weight']=float(c)

edges,weights = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight').items())

##DRAW GRAPH##
nx.draw(G, pos, edgelist=edges, edge_color=weights, width=5.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues, node_color=[color_map[G.node[node]['category']] for node in G])
```

But I have two kind of possible connection between nodes, with for each kind different possible weights, so I would like to plot my graph using two different color maps for edges. Is there any issue ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution thanks to `nx.draw_networkx_edges` :

```
#one group with one color map :
edges = tuple(list_edgesG1)
weights = tuple([G[e][f]['weight'] for e,f in edges]) 
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edges, edge_color=weights, width=3.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds)

#the other group with different color map :
edges2 = tuple(list_edgesG2)
weights2 = tuple([G[e][f]['weight'] for e,f in edges2])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G , pos, edgelist=edges2, edge_color=weights2, width=3.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```